# Sharing ArcMap document to a lower version

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am working with ArcGIS 10.4.1 and need to share a map package to someone working with ArcGIS 10.2.2.

I am able to save a copy to a lower version ArcGIS i.e 10.1 to 10.2 option. However, to make a map package I still have to reopen this in 10.4.1!

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use "Package Map" tool from Data Management>Package

This will give you the option 'Package Version' all the way back to 10.0.

[image]

If you have trouble opening the map package, try using the **"Extract Package"** tool from Data Management>Package

Comment: Ok, i jumped the gun on this one. i keep getting Error opening map package ,invalid map package! What could be the cause of this?

Comment: If you have trouble opening the map package, try using the **"Extract Package"** tool from Data Management>Package

Comment: I tried using the 'Extract Package' tool, still doesn't work. i get error 999999. i have also tried unpacking it through arccatalogue, doesn't work as well.

Comment: Please post your settings.